# Swap first two elements of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm doing this exercise from [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse16):

> Exercise  4.4
>   Write a predicate swap12(List1,List2) which checks whether List1 is
>   identical to List2 , except that the first two elements are exchanged.

This is what I have so far:

```
swap12([],[]).
swap12([a, b | Ta], [b, a | Tb]) :- swap12(Ta, Tb).
```

But when I try to evaluate this I get the following:

```
?- swap12(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = [a, b],
Y = [b, a] ;
X = [a, b, a, b],
Y = [b, a, b, a] .
```

What am I doing wrong?

The goal is to have something like the following:

```
swap12(X,Y).
X = [a, b].
Y = [b, a].
X = [a, b, b].
Y = [b, a, a].
```

etc. Please help!

Comment: The problem is to swap only the first two elements. You're making a recursive call which will swap each successive pair of elements. Also, you are using atoms, not variables. Atoms start with a lower case letter. Variables start with a capital letter or `_`. So you should write `swap12([A,B|T], [B,A|T]).` which is all you need to swap the first two elements of any list, *e.g.*, `swap([a,b,c,d], L).` would yield `L = [b,a,c,d]`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. do you mean redefine `swap12` as `swap12([A, B|T], [B, A|T])`? or pass different arguments to the existing function?

Comment: I mean *redefine*. You don't need anything else. `swap([A, B|T], [B, A|T]).` says that `[B, A|T]` is `[A, B|T]` with the first two elements swapped (and they're otherwise identical since they share the same tail, `T`). Doesn't that sound like a complete definition to solve the problem? You should try it if you're still not sure.

Comment: Can you please add an example as an answer to the question?

Comment: I provided a more detailed answer with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first clause:

```
swap12([],[]).
```

Says that swapping the first two elements of the empty list is the empty list. I suppose, perhaps, by definition one might say that. But since the empty list has no elements, it may not really be considered to be true.

Your second clause is:

```
swap12([a, b | Ta], [b, a | Tb]) :- swap12(Ta, Tb).
```

This says that *if you swap the first two elements of `[a, b | Ta]` the result is `[b, a | Tb]` if `Tb` is `Ta` with its first two elements swapped*. This is a rule for any list that starts with `a` and `b`, but won't work if you have any other first two elements because `a` and `b` are *atoms*, not *variables*. Thus, for example, `swap12([1,2,3,4], L)` would fail since your list starts with `1` and `2`, not `a` and `b`. In addition, your problem is to swap *ONLY* the first two elements, whereas your solution has the recursive call to `swap12(Ta, Tb)` which continues to swap recursively.

Here's what your code really does (it doesn't do what you show in your question, which means the results you show is for a different version of the code you wrote).

```
?- swap12([a,b], R).
R = [b,a].

?- swap12([b,a], R).
false.    % This fails because `b`, `a` doesn't match `a`, `b`.

?- swap12([a,b,c], R).
false.    % This fails because [a,b,c] has an odd number of elements

?- swap12([a,b,c,d], R).
false.    % This fails because `c`, `d` doesn't match `a` and `b`

?- swap12([a,b,a,b], R).
R = [b, a, b, a].

?- swap12(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = [a, b],
Y = [b, a] ;
X = [a, b, a, b],
Y = [b, a, b, a] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b],
Y = [b, a, b, a, b, a] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b],
Y = [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a] ;
...
```

The last execution shows you what your rules really mean. It succeeds only if the first list is empty, or any number of `a`, `b` pairs and the second list is the same with each `a`, `b` pair swapped to `b`, `a`.

Let's start over. The problem, again, is to create a rule that is true if the second list is the first list with *ONLY* the first two elements swapped. A list that has at least two elements looks like `[X, Y|T]` (the first two elements are `X` and `Y` - variables). If I want to swap *ONLY* the first two elements, I would write, `[Y, X|T]` so I have swapped `X` and `Y`, but keep the *same* tail, `T` (I do not want to swap any more elements).

Thus, the rule simply looks like:

```
swap12([X, Y|T], [Y, X|T]).
```

This says that if I have a list `[X, Y|T]`, then `[Y, X|T]` is the same list but with just the first two elements swapped. You can try it out:

```
?- swap12([a], R).
false.       % fails because `[a]` only has one element!

?- swap12([a,b], R).
R = [b, a].

?- swap12([a,b,c], R).
R = [b, a, c].

?- swap12([a,b,c,d], R).
R = [b, a, c, d].

?- swap12([a,b,c,e,f], R).
R = [b, a, c, e, f].

?- ...
```

Comment: how could i do the same, but for all elements, not only for first two?
I guess i need to use recursion to loop over each pair

Comment: @MiRAY you need to be more specific about what it means to do the swap for "all elements". For example, do you mean swapping *any* pair of elements? Or do you mean swapping *every* pair (1st, and 2nd, 3rd and 4th, etc) of elements? What if the list has an odd number of elements? Perhaps you should post a new question on this site and specify what you're looking for. But search the site first as it may have already been answered.

Comment: this is a example of the outpuit:  ?− swapevery2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], X).
X = [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]. Each two numbers are considered a pair. (1,2) - first pair, (3,4) second pair and (5,6) third pair. After switching result would be X = [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]. Hope i expained what is my goal.

Comment: @MiRAY should probably be a separate question, but yes you just need to make it recursive. What do you expect for `X = [1, 2, 3]`? You would have the trivial base case of `swap12([], [])` (an empty list is the swap of an empty list). Then `swap12([A, B|T], [B, A|TS]) :- swap12(T, TS).` if you only want it to work with even number of elements. This example will fail for `X = [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: ok , let me make another question for this. Here is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599198/swap-each-pair-of-two-elements-of-a-list-prolog

Comment: for X = [1, 2, 3] output should be X = [2, 1, 3] btw

Comment: @MiRAY Just add another base case to the solution I showed in my comment. Your question is likely to get downvoted because it's just asking for a solution without any attempt to solve it yourself and no specific question about where you're stuck trying to solve it. You really should be able to think through a solution to your case by studying the examples on hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240768/discussion-between-miray-and-lurker).